# Jquery children или find

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день!
Помогите решить такую задачу:
есть код html

```
<div class="select1">
    <a class="zag" title="">сортировать по</a>
    <div class="list_sort">
        <ul>
            <li><a title="">привлекательности</a></li>
            <li><a title="">просмотрам</a></li>
            <li><a title="">активности</a></li>
            <li><a title="">дате</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

При клике на тег с классом zag должен отображать тег с классом list_sort (изначально он display:none), только это все нужно сделать без использования id и в коде JS. Смысл в чем - на странице будет куча таких селектов и для каждого прописывать id нет смысла.
Сейчас пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select1 .zag").click(function() {
        $(this).find('.list_sort').toggle();
    });
```

Но ничего не получается, помогите, плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ищите **div.list_sort** внутри **a.zag**.
Надо так:

```
$(this).parent().find('.list_sort').toggle();
```

Comment: спасибо, все ок